# Cannot use instance member 'URLParent' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Tags: swift

I was trying to get data from one view controller but it didn't work and this happened

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class VideoViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {
    
    var URLParent = VideoChooserViewController(nibName: "ChooseVideo", bundle: nil)
    var URL_link=URLParent.YouTubeURL    //Error: Cannot use instance member 'URLParent' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
    
    var myURL = URL(string: URL_link)
    
    //var webView = WKWebView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```